# Best statistical test for aggregated group rate vs individual rate?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, percentage, z-test, weighted-mean

I'm looking to test the difference between an aggregated group weight (weighted average) vs an individual group rate?

For example:

Let's say we have 4 companies:
A - 35/60 = 58%
B - 120 / 400 = 30%
C - 80/100 = 80%

If I add the counts and then average I get 235/560 = ~42%. However, the weighted average is 56%.

I'm not interested in knowing whether there is a difference between all these companies. I specifically want to test whether the weighted average is different to company D (30/70 = ~43%).

If I use a Chi-square with the total counts of the companies, I don't really test the weighted average of A, B, C against D.

What I'd like to confirm is whether a proportions z test is the most appropriate and reliable test for this scenario?

Comment: Can you clarify: in each of these companies do you have multiple observations of some quantity, which ultimately you average out? So in your Company A example there are 60 underlying observations? You're not starting with an aggregate?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am starting from counts. However, it matters that I used a weighted rate for all companies for comparison. Which is why I can't add the count data directly and use it in a Chi-square.